# How to create a page-stop scroll animation

Tags: scroll

The new mini-site for iPhone 5s has a special page scroll:

http://www.apple.com/iphone-5s/

Every time you flick the page, it glides and stops at the next full page, not halfway, and not any more than required. How do they do it?

Comment: You disable scrolling, have dynamic element sizes based on the window, and animate a scroll the height of the window (to go to the next one). Next time try inspecting the page and provide code you've attempted along with the question of what problem you are having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnePageScroll may be what you're looking for: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/09/18/onepagescroll-js-creating-an-apples-iphone-5s-website/

Comment: Thanks, that's a great find.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do a similar site and I created a plugin for it:
http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/fullpage-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/

- [Living demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

In mine you can also:

- Use it over IE 8 and old browsers with no CSS 3 support.
- Slide throw the page using the keyboard arrows.
- Add horizontal sliders.
- Resize of texts when resizing the window.
- Mobile and Tablet detection enabling the scrolling on them. (as there are usually problems to visualize big contents and texts)

It is in its first version, simple but working well :)

I will keep improving it as far as I can. Suggestions will be more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I've been fiddling with a solution to a similar problem.

All my solution does is monitor when the window scrolls.

```
if ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()>=$("#page"+(nextpage)).offset().top+100) {
```

If it scrolls past the end of the "page" by more than 50px jquery animates the scroll to the next "page".

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: pageheight }, 500, function() { currentpage = nextpage; animatingdown = false; document.location.hash = currentpage;});
```

It does the same for scrolling up. This covers scrolling by mouse, keyboard or javascript.

Check out the full code at http://jsfiddle.net/dLCwC/1/

Maybe it'll be of some use to someone (let me know if it is, or isn't).